# How to get rid of lists when writing the parsed xml file into text file using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, xml-parsing, beautifulsoup

I have an xml file of following format:

```
<date>31,March,2001</date>
<post>



       urlLink The Register reports on "war driving"  - the wireless equivalent of war dialing.  Instead of having your modem dial into thousands of networks until you get in, you just drive within range of a wireless net with your wireless-equipped laptop and hack away.    related:   urlLink The latest issue of CIO  has a great feature on wireless.



</post>
```

I want to extract the content of each post and write it on a new line on my output text file. Here is my code for parsing it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
def parseLog(file):
        with open(file, 'rb') as handler:
            soup = Soup(handler, "html.parser")
            for message in soup.findAll('post'):
                #print(len(str(message).strip()))
                content = message.contents
                if(len(str(content).strip()) > 300):
                    re.sub("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "", str(content))
                    with open(dest, 'a', encoding="utf-8") as f:
                        f.write(str(message.contents) + "\n")
```

However, the output file now contains each content as a list instead. Also, there are unwanted "\r" and "\n" characters everywhere ( I used re.sub() to get rid of these but it didn't work):

> ['\r\n\r\n\r\n       \r\n      Quotable Mindjack!  From Mike
>   Sugarbaker\'s  urlLink review of Lemon :  "If you have no patience for
>   the lengthy ruminations of brilliant madmen, Lemon isn\'t for you. But
>   you read Mindjack, so you\'re probably into that sort of thing,
>   right?"\r\n     \r\n\r\n    \r\n']['\r\n\r\n\r\n       \r\n      I\'m
>   not sure I like the direction  urlLink FEED just turned .  "The
>   filter", a new weblog linking to outside content is now featured more
>   prominently than FEED\'s original content.  It\'s also not clear what
>   the difference is between the filter and  urlLink Plastic .\r\n
>   \r\n\r\n    \r\n']

How to get rid of these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`message.contents` is a `list`. You should use `get_text()` instead:

```
def parseLog(file):
        with open(file, 'rb') as handler:
            soup = Soup(handler, "html.parser")
            for message in soup.findAll('post'):
                content = message.get_text() #a string!
                if(len(content.strip()) > 300):
                    re.sub("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "", str(content))
                    with open(dest, 'a', encoding="utf-8") as f:
                        f.write(content + "\n")
```